# Filter nested array in object based on specific values of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array of Objects, and every object has an array of strings (tags), I need to filter the array of objects based on another array.

```
data: [
       {
          "id":"Nerium",
          "tags":["CMS Selection", "Experience Design", "Development","UX"],
          "featured":0
       },
       {
          "id":"WesternDigital",
          "tags":["Digital Strategy", "Analytics", "Example"],
          "featured":1
       },
       {
          "id":"Example",
          "tags":["Example", "Analytics", "UX"],
          "featured": 0,
       },
```

I need to filter the above data based on an Array like this:

```
activeTags: ['UX', 'Example']
```

And the objects of Data I filter need to specifically have the values inside activeTags, in this case if for example an Object has 'UX' but it doesn't have 'Example', I don't return it.

Expected output:

```
data: [{
  "id": "Example",
  "tags": ["Example", "Analytics", "UX"],
  "featured": 0,
}]
```

Or it should return every Object that has tags that specifically have the values in activeTags

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Something like:
let filtered = data.filter(item=> item.tags.some(tag => activeTags.includes(tag)))

Comment: Please add to your question the desired output for the example, your current code, and the errors/issues with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "Nerium",
    tags: ["CMS Selection", "Experience Design", "Development", "UX"],
    featured: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "WesternDigital",
    tags: ["Digital Strategy", "Analytics", "Example"],
    featured: 1,
  },
  {
    id: "Example",
    tags: ["Example", "Analytics", "UX"],
    featured: 0,
  },
];

const activeTags = ["UX", "Example"];

const filtered = data.filter(({ tags }) =>
  activeTags.every((tag) => tags.includes(tag))
);

console.log(filtered);
```

you can use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that the object has all the active tags

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested, but I think the following should work:

```
const result = data.filter( record =>
    activeTags.every( tag =>
        record.tags.includes( tag )
    )
);
```

`filter()` returns array with only elements that pass its function test. `every()` returns true only if every element passes its function test. `includes()` will test if the element is included in the `record.tags` array.